# Type as const without using as const

Tags: typescript

I have a constant similar to this in my project

Note: I am using typescript version `4.8.2`

```js
export const test = [
  { key: 'gdsfg', value: 'gsdf' },
  { key: 'ofadwned', value: 'gsdfgs' },
]; // type of test is -> const test: { key: string; value: string;}[]
```

If I use `as const` at the end of constant I get the following type which I am expecting

```js
export const test = [
  { key: 'gdsfg', value: 'gsdf' },
  { key: 'ofadwned', value: 'gsdfgs' },
] as const; // type of test is -> const test: readonly [{readonly key: "gdsfg";readonly value: "gsdf";}, {readonly key: "ofadwned";readonly value: "gsdfgs";}]
```

As this const is used in multiple places in the project, I can't add `as const` at the end of it an break the existing type system

Is there any other way in typescript to achieve this? something like

```js
type expectedType = (typeof test) as const; // This is currently not possible in Typescript
// I want expectedType is of type -> readonly [{readonly key: "gdsfg";readonly value: "gsdf";}, {readonly key: "ofadwned";readonly value: "gsdfgs";}]
```

My use-case is not only checking the type but also extracting multiple types from the const which is not possible with type annotation.

Code sample:

```js
// Legacy code start >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

type KeyValue = {key: string, value: string};

// These constants are used in multiple places with this type
// I can't change these as it breaks ifExists function constant type
const constants1: KeyValue[] = [
  { key: 'key1', value: 'gsdf' },
  { key: 'key2', value: 'gsdfgs' },
];

const constants2: KeyValue[] = [
  { key: 'key3', value: 'gsdghjkghjngff' },
  { key: 'key4', value: 'jfgjgrhr' },
  { key: 'key5', value: 'erqwe' },
];

// Just added simple function to simulate the behaviour but acutal function has more complex types and structure
// I can't change this
const ifExists = (checkValue: string, constant: KeyValue[]) => {
    return constant.find(c => c.key === checkValue)
}

const check = ifExists('afsd', constants1)

// Legacy code ends >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>


// Code I have control
type CustomType = {
    property1: string,
    validKey: 'key1' | 'key2' | 'key3' | 'key4' | 'key5' // keys from constant1 and constant2
    // This is the type I am expecting to be dynamic, I don't want to update this type when new constant is added or existing one is updated
}

// api response
const responseFromBackend: CustomType = {
    property1: 'dfasdfasf',
    validKey: 'key5'
}

// My question - can I get the literal type of a const without actually using as const, something like follows

// I want CustomConstant1 to be of type 'key1' | 'key2'
type CustomConstant1 = ((typeof constants1) as const)[number]['key'] // This doesn't work

// I want to have type validKey in CustomType dynamically
```

Please refer the code sample
[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBkFMHMEMGMCep4HsAmlQGcAusAnXUAPjPIspIChrdEAHLAaUkQDVYAbAVywF5QAbwDWbAFw5cBAJYA7aABpQAN259JeWQoC+AblohQAFQAWkbFjRy8sObmyhCWHpfSh5oALY8uuGQxcWIEIFqAA7jK4pqDRMo70TNRGAJIodgDkxPCmdtBY0RZYsI5RoABGBJCwIqUAZgCiAB7xDqB1PHLw-qhyKL229rGMkNTWeP02+PbYAIySrBzqkADaALqggivUoMKgYoiSGQezGcpqvJBH0NjodRmgOoo7ewdHBwBMZ6rL17d1NweT2oawMYwG2QhdgcHwWbE4l3Wm1A212Qn2ElAxzYAGZvhcNFibuhoKYAFYiUlkhR1e6PZ5ojGHLEHAAs+N+WLJALJ0AIpgIQIZr0x2MQAFYOZcjpACABHcKQIUgsFGABSrmIsHQmHc2BkXkCWA6XR6fVwqBwBt8sFwBXMFUguRUMlQPAIFR4WvgXu47U63VdfVyji8qCq-UNQSawyYjjseukPG67tGqXSciyKFyCnt8XBUw8jRaeEcggAFDlIPARAjCVp5EpJoNcHCloi1gBKTYkYQvXZVXDuvrjaa4AB0dXk6ErPZQ44Om34girNbrkE71B0tFH2erImRMmLrWw5YysDqt2+o+hc03yTAUDgSH6mFAkDk6EcVB-VFoD9AABhDAsDSZ0rF6aRUC4OgRiAzVUC8Yw4MEIR+1ABgCFQJgiEQeYpG0JR0IuGR0EWd42FOUAAB8WTYL4aLoxA8UYsV2VYg5JVAIwDkcOosK8Zsx1mJxPyE6EPnQowzHiDwEgdRJQKcQTICaJhAwUWJLXKLB0EQORYC8GR4GUNJ0F6LNwmhLTQB4Bh0FtPMEjg8JzD6ORIHCcShlk7VdVAcN3xLfxNN6LBZLshy7XQLdDDAWAGBkUAqmwBgBlGXcUrSmxIAAMQEgAhBAxE-SRAIQpCUL7XZdkw7DZXofCMjuEoWuwe5hV2EiyNFTiMligCAFlkDlPg8CDUAAFoM1ANJ8mIQpQC4KJZT9RSArqJwhIiKJTDdb0h24LhkFcRsnEcUdlGwRDIDiTTlrEdpoK4VBwmwOLZoiazyrwRDgKmaERItR0NtjLAxSo2ixS+WCmHg36vH+lsRIrctFNQTabxmWZuxKITOxWOQeC8HSCDWFYxQyDZpNMWTzIsTNiHCcMRA+tIrKGYHwLBn5lp65BPB+i1KrhvSDKM+AjsQIA).

Comment: Why not actually add a type annotation? Then the compiler can _check_ what you're writing.

Comment: My usecase is not only checking the type but also extracting multiple types from the const which is not possible with type annotation.

Comment: If you only want to prevent modifications but are otherwise happy with the type `{ key: string; value: string;}[]`, would [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) satisfy your need? (This triggers runtime errors for modification attempts at runtime, not necessarily compile time errors - but since you use this only in tests, that would probably be ok?)

Comment: I need a literal type but preventing modifications will be an added advantage.

Comment: "I can't add `as const` at the end of it an[d] break the existing type system" Can you elaborate on this?  What specifically breaks?  A [mre] would be very helpful.  I would suggest `as const satisfies XXX` where `XXX` is the type you would otherwise use to annotate, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3KKEm), but I don't know if that works for you.  Please [edit] to clarify and hopefully add a [mre].

Comment: Added a code sample

Comment: ① Please put the code sample in the question as plaintext as well; code that is only available as a link does not suffice to be a [mre] ② If you are not allowed to modify your "legacy" code at all then what you're asking for is impossible.  If you are allowed to modify the code than you need to add `as const` [and I don't see anything that "breaks" in your example](https://tsplay.dev/wOXXrN) so it still doesn't seem to be a [mre]. Could you [edit] to clarify further?

Comment: Updated the question with the code sample, sorry I forgot to mention the version of typescript earlier. This issue is reproducible in v4.8.2/v4.8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with `satisfies` keyword as pointed out by the @jcalz in the comments.

Note: `satisfies` keyword is added to Typescript in v4.9

Answer (score -1):

You're right that as const creates a readonly version of the object properties. However, if you cannot modify the original constant directly due to its use in multiple places, you might consider creating a utility type that transforms the properties of your object type into readonly.

One way to achieve this is by using mapped types in TypeScript. You can create a utility type that takes an object type and converts its properties into readonly.

```
// Your original type without `as const`
type OriginalType = {
  key: string;
  value: string;
};

// Utility type to convert properties to readonly
type ToReadonly<T> = {
  readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

// Your constant
const test = [
  { key: 'gdsfg', value: 'gsdf' },
  { key: 'ofadwned', value: 'gsdfgs' },
] as const;

// Extract the type of the constant and transform its properties to readonly
type ExpectedType = ToReadonly<typeof test[number]>;

// Now ExpectedType represents a readonly version of your constant's properties
// expectedType is of type: readonly [{ readonly key: "gdsfg"; readonly value: "gsdf"; }, { readonly key: "ofadwned"; readonly value: "gsdfgs"; }]
```

The **ToReadonly** utility type takes a type **T** and converts all its properties into **readonly**. In this case, **typeof test[number]** extracts the union type of the array elements, and **ToReadonly** transforms each property to **readonly**.

You can use the **ExpectedType** type alias wherever you need this transformed readonly version of your object properties without directly modifying the original constant.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I want to achieve this without using `as const`.